# How is my 'snackBarMessage' Automatically Assigned Without Being Defined in the 'data' Function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm a beginner at web development and Vue. I'm working on a basic project in Vuetify with Vue.JS 3. In one of my views, I have a table that emits a message and fetch status to show a snackbar to user:

```
methods: {
    async fetchVehicles() {
      await api
        .get(vehiclesForTable.getAll)
        .then((response) => {
          this.vehicles = response.data.data;
          this.snackBarMessage = response.data.message;
          this.isSuccess = response.data.success;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.snackBarMessage = "Bilinmeyen hata meydana geldi.";
          this.isSuccess = false;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.$emit("open-snackbar", this.isSuccess, this.snackBarMessage);
        });
    },
    openDetailsDialog(id) {
      this.$emit("toggle-detail", id);
    },
    openEditDialog(id) {
      this.$emit("toggle-edit", id);
    },
    openAddDialog(id) {
      this.$emit("toggle-add", id);
    },
    openDeleteDialog(id) {
      this.$emit("toggle-delete", id);
    },
},
```

*I am using axios to fetch my data*

But the thing is, I don't have any "isSuccess" or "snackBarMessage" in my Data function as shown in below.

```
data() {
  return {
    vehicles: [],
    headers: [...],
    searchText: "",
  };
},
```

So, how could my code work? Of course, it could be a local variable but I'm calling them by "this."

Thanks in advance.

This is not an error, but I got confused. There is nothing to solve but something to learn apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Vue with `Options API` approach. `This` is your component's instance.
Not having `isSuccess` or `snackBarMessage` in `data` is not a good code, it might lead to missing reactivity, you should define them before referencing them.

**But how does the code work?**

If you don't have `isSuccess` or `snackBarMessage` in your component's `data` they would be just `undefined`. Code won't brake in that case, they are just properties.

**Here's another example**: if you try to invoke the function that doesn't exist (=== `undefined`) you would get a `TypeError`.

**Back to the code:**

In `then` and `catch` you assign values to `isSuccess` or `snackBarMessage` properties that means in `finally` they won't be `undefined` anyway. That's why your snackbar will always show something. But again - you should add these properties to the `data` object to allow `Vue` track them properly.

Comment: Thanks but I want to be sure: Vue/JavaScript created these variables temporarily and after the fetch funciton, I can't access them right?

Comment: They are not created temporarily, they are properties of ```data``` object like others, but they are not reactive, as far as I know. You can access them. Imagine you have an object = ```{ a: 1, b: 3 }```. If you try to access ```c```, you'd get ```undefined```, in your component you have the same thing. You can create a simple method that logs in console those properties after the fetch, you'll see that they are logged.